# ASK How to extract email regex using Emeditor? get email specific

Tags: regex, text-editors, email-filter

example :

```
hello this my email user1@domains.com contact me
yes this my email user2@needthis.ca:contactmenow
user:3:user3@needthistoo.com.au:contactme
hello this is my email andre,user4@needthis.co.uk,
hello ... this is my email user5@other.com
```

---

I need result like this (delete all not specific email address character and extract it) using regex (emdeditor):

```
user1@domains.com
user2@needthis.ca
user3@needtistoo.com.au
user4@needthis.co.uk
```

so email user5@other.com deleted help please.
thankyou.

Comment: Why `user5@other.com` must be deleted? What are the rules?

Comment: What this have to do with outlook?

Comment: because I no want extract <pre>user5@other.com</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job with Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(?:user5@other\.com|([^\s,:]+@[^\s:,]+)).*?$`
- Replace with: `(?1$1:)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                           # beginning of line
  .*?                       # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (?:                       # non capture group
      user5@other\.com      # literally
    |                     # OR
      (                     # group 1
        [^\s,:]+            # 1 or more any character that is not space, comma or colon
        @                   # @
        [^\s,:]+            # 1 or more any character that is not space, comma or colon
      )                     # end group 1
  )                         # end group
  .*?                       # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
$                           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
  $1        # take it
  :         # else, nothing
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: how to I extract spesific email domain?

Comment: if I use (?:                       # non capture group it's waste time because too much email need for delete

Comment: @Benjamin: which specific domain? Why is it waste time? Sorry, I don't get you, what do you want exactly? Edit your question with real test cases with expected result.